# How to add items enclosed by < > to documentation comments

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, documentation, comments

I am trying to write documentation comments however I have a problem.

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts an element into the System.Collections.Generic.List<T> at the specified
/// index.
/// </summary>
```

When I reach the `<T>` Visual studio thinks I am trying to add another tag. what is the correct way to add comments like that (and if I could make them click able in the generated help text that would be a extra bonus)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# documentation comments are XML, so change your `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

What you're better off doing, though is, is using the `<see>` tag to insert a hyperlink. In a `<see>` tag, change `<T>` to `{T}`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts an element into the <see cref="List{T}"/> at the specified
/// index.
/// </summary>
```

(Note that the `cref` attribute is syntax-checked by the compiler, unlike ordinary text.)

Answer (score 2):

escape the xml entities.

```
Change <T> into &lt;T&gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would be of help for you: [C# XML documentation comments FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/ansonh/archive/2006/09/11/750056.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I always love a well written FAQ

Comment: I'm glad if it helps - it certainly has proved useful to me at times.

Answer (score 0):

Since the comment is xml you can use appropriate escape sequences for xml:

```
/// Inserts an element into the System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;T&gt; at the specified
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the proper char codes: `&lt`; and `&gt`;.

You would want to surreound the whole *System.Collections.Generic.List<T>* in a `<see cref="..."/>` tag.

I actually had to use the above mentioned tags to correctly write this answer :)