# How to refer to array types in documentation comments

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, documentation, comments

[I just posted this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367357/how-to-add-items-enclosed-by-to-documentation-comments) and learned about `<see cref="">`, however when i tried

```
/// This is a set of extensions that allow more operations on a <see cref="byte[]"/>.
```

The compiler gave me warnings about it not being formatted correctly. What do I need to do so it will see the code reference correctly?

Comment: I don't think this is an objection to [] per se, more about the compiler not being able to recognise `byte[]` as a linkable type.  I've changed the title of your question to reflect this: please roll back if you disagree or think I'm wrong.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761104/using-cs-xml-comment-cref-attribute-with-params-syntax), use

```
 <see cref="T:byte[]" />
```

Comment: I was trying to do this with `T:string[]`, and it wasn't working. `Array.string` seemed to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can write like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Array byte <see cref="byte"/>[]
/// Nullable byte <see cref="byte"/>?
/// </summary>
```

or

```
/// <summary>
/// Array byte <see cref="T:byte[]"/>
/// Nullable byte <see cref="T:byte?"/>
/// </summary>
```

Answer (score -3):

You should perhaps have `<summary>...</summary>` around:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a set of extensions that allow more operations on a <see cref="byte[]"/>.
/// </summary>
```

Comment: I did but i cut it from the example because i didn't want to type 3 lines.